# R pivot multiple columns into long format

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape, tidyr

I've got a wide format person-level data frame that I'm trying to melt into a long format summary table. Sample code and examples are below:

```
set.seed(100)

#Original wide format person level data
dat_wide <- tibble(group = rep(x = c('a','b','c'), each = 5),
                   d1 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_integer_), size = 15, replace = TRUE),
                   d2 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_integer_), size = 15, replace = TRUE),
                   d3 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_integer_), size = 15, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(d1_br = case_when(
    d1 == 1 ~ .8,
    d1 == 0 ~ .2,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ),
  d2_br = case_when(
    d2 == 1 ~ .6,
    d2 == 0 ~ .4,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ),
  d3_br = case_when(
    d3 == 1 ~ .95,
    d3 == 0 ~ .05,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))
dat_wide

# A tibble: 15 x 7
   group    d1    d2    d3 d1_br d2_br d3_br
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         0    NA     0   0.2  NA    0.05
 2 a         1     0     0   0.8   0.4  0.05
 3 a         1    NA     1   0.8  NA    0.95
 4 a         1    NA    NA   0.8  NA   NA   
 5 a         0    NA     1   0.2  NA    0.95
 6 b        NA     0     1  NA     0.4  0.95
 7 b        NA    NA     1  NA    NA    0.95
 8 b        NA     0     1  NA     0.4  0.95
 9 b         1     0     0   0.8   0.4  0.05
10 b         1     1    NA   0.8   0.6 NA   
11 c         0    NA     1   0.2  NA    0.95
12 c         0    NA     0   0.2  NA    0.05
13 c        NA    NA     1  NA    NA    0.95
14 c         1    NA     0   0.8  NA    0.05
15 c         0     1     0   0.2   0.6  0.05

#Long format summary table
dat_long <- tibble(group = rep(c('a','b','b'), each = 9),
                   dv = rep(c('d1','d2','d3'), each = 3, times = 3),
                   response = rep(c(1, 0, NA_integer_), times = 9)) %>% 
  mutate(br = case_when(
    dv == 'd1' & response == 1 ~ .8,
    dv == 'd1' & response == 0 ~ .2,
    dv == 'd2' & response == 1 ~ .6,
    dv == 'd2' & response == 0 ~ .4,
    dv == 'd3' & response == 1 ~ .95,
    dv == 'd3' & response == 0 ~ .05,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))

# A tibble: 27 x 4
   group dv    response    br
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     d1           1  0.8 
 2 a     d1           0  0.2 
 3 a     d1          NA NA   
 4 a     d2           1  0.6 
 5 a     d2           0  0.4 
 6 a     d2          NA NA   
 7 a     d3           1  0.95
 8 a     d3           0  0.05
 9 a     d3          NA NA   
10 b     d1           1  0.8 
# ... with 17 more rows
```

I'm fairly certain this can be accomplished with `tidyr::pivot_longer` though I'm new to using it and haven't figured out all of it's capabilities. Something akin to the following should work, but could someone help fill in the pivot_longer syntax? Do I need to the `names_sep` or `names_prefix` arguments? I haven't wrapped my head around those yet.

```
#Possible solution
dat_long <- dat_wide %>% 
  # pivot_longer(...) %>% 
  distinct(group, dv, response, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier if you have the numerical values in column names consistently at the end. If you rename `dat_wide`:

```
names(dat_wide) <- sub("(\\w+)(\\d+)(\\w*)", "\\1\\3\\2", names(dat_wide))
```

`d1_br` will become `d_br1` etc.

Then you can use `pivot_longer` with two sets of columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group, 
               names_to = c(".value", "dv"),
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)") %>%
  distinct(group, dv, d, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(group, dv)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
   group dv        d  d_br
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     1         0  0.2 
 2 a     1        NA NA   
 3 a     1         1  0.8 
 4 a     2        NA NA   
 5 a     2         0  0.4 
 6 a     2         1  0.6 
 7 a     3        NA NA   
 8 a     3         0  0.05
 9 a     3         1  0.95
10 b     1         0  0.2
```

Comment: I'm working on implementing this at the moment. Can you explain what the .value sentinel actually does?

Comment: The special `.value` sentinel indicates the names of your `value` columns (in this case, `d` and `d_br`). We didn't need to use `values_to` to indicate where values would go in `pivot_longer`. Based on `names_pattern` regex you will get 2 different components. The first is the string/word before the number, which is `d` or `d_br`. When you use `.value` in `names_to` then these become the column names where your values are stored. The second component is the number 1, 2, or 3, extracted from the original column names which is then included under a new `dv` column.

Comment: This did work though it adjusted the values, and I had to fix them back to their original values. I still don't really understand what I did, but thank you for your help.